# QGraphicsView: Snake-Line and Line animation

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I have two questions regarding the **QGraphicsView Framework**.

The first question is regarding a special line: I wanted to ask whether it is possible to draw an **Snake- or Wave-Line** (like in the linked image)? I would be grateful for any solution, because I dont have any idea how to get the sinus-shaped line.

[Image: a snake line](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3030074/images/snakeline.png)

My second question is about the `QGraphicsItemAnimation`- I want to animate a `QGraphicsLineItem`. Right now I am using the method `setPosAt()` from the QGraphicsItemAnimation. The problem is, that the hole line is moved. My aim is to move only the **start or the end point** of the `QGraphicsLineItem` with the `QGraphicsItemAnimation`. So I want to ask whether this is possible or whether there is any other way to do something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards
- PhiGamma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question : Probably a couple of ways:

a. Use `QPainterPath` and the `cubicTo()` method to create the "path", then use `QGraphicsPath` with the path you create. In order to do this, you'll need to approximate the sinewave using bezier curves. Some info on that [here](http://www.tinaja.com/glib/bezsine.pdf), and the QPainterPath documentation is [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpainterpath.html)

b. Subclass `QGraphicsItem()` and override the `paint()` event to draw your path using `QPainter`.

```
Sinewave::Sinewave( QGraphicsItem* pParent ) : QGraphicsObject( pParent)
{
    m_bounds = QRectF(0,0,150,100);
}

QRectF Sinewave::boundingRect() const
{
    return m_bounds;
}

void Sinewave::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    unsigned int i;
    QPointF last(0,50);
    const int numberOfCycles = 4.0;
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    for (int i = 0; i < boundingRect().width(); i++)
    {
        double radians = numberOfCycles * 2.0 * PI * static_cast<double>(i) / boundingRect().width();
        double y = sin(radians);
        QPointF next(i, 50 + y*50);
        painter->drawLine(last, next);
        last = next;
    }
}
```

Which one you use would depend on what you want the object to do (e.g. do you need to change it's shape at runtime?).

For your question about animation - no, you can only apply transforms with QGraphcisItemAnimation. I would do it by using a QTimer to drive the change you want in your items in it's timeout() slot.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following algorithm for displaying a sine wave:

```
const double PI = 3.14159267;
unsigned int i;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 400; ++i)
{
    double radians = static_cast<double>(i) / 100.0;
    double y = sin(radians);
    set_point(radians, y);
}
```

By adding an offset to the 'y' value, you can move the sine wave up or down.
Adding a constant to the 'radians' (or X ordinate) will move the sine wave left or right.